# An application tells me I need .NET Framework 2.0.50727?

Tags: .net-framework, windows-8-preview

When trying to install an application, it is asking for .NET Framework 2.0.50727.

[image]

Where do I get the right installer?

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but what happens when you press "Yes"?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: Bring you to the .NET Framework site, which is not 2.0.50727... :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the Windows Features UI to install it.

1. Open the Start Menu
2. Type "Windows Features"
3. Select Settings on the search pane
4. Click on "Turn Windows Features On and Off"
5. Find and click on .Net Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
6. Complete the install wizard (it will download the appropriate bits)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the 32-bit installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19) and the 64-bit installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6523).

These will install 2.0 as well as 3.0, Windows 8 should already have 1.0 and 4.0 as well as 4.5 beta.